# Problema com thread em BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

Estou aprendendo agora a usar o BackgroundWorker e estou tendo esse problema pra acessar as informações de alguns chekbox na MainWindow, andei pesquisando sobre o Dispatcher mas não consegui entender bem como implementar aqui.
"O thread de chamada não pode acessar este objeto porque ele pertence a um thread diferente"

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            
            
             //ERRO AQUI
            if (check1.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(1);
            }
            if (check2.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(2);
            }
            if (check3.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(3);
            }
            if (check4.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(4);
            }
            if (check5.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(5);
            }
            #endregion
            
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode colocar o acesso aos controles dentro de um contexto que seja suncronizado com a Thread da UI.

```
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>  
           {  
            if (check1.IsChecked == true)
            {
               qualidades.Add(1);
            }
            if (check2.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(2);
            }
            if (check3.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(3);
            }
            if (check4.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(4);
            }
            if (check5.IsChecked == true)
            {
                qualidades.Add(5);
            } 
           }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/update-ui-with-wpf-dispatcher-and-tpl/).